# Antd change message.success icon color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am currently trying to change the theme of antd. However I am unable to change the icon color for messages:

[image: Example success message]

This is what I currently have:

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        yellow: colors.yellow500,
        blue: colors.blue500,
        green: colors.teal500,
        red: colors.red400,
        colorPrimary: colors.blue500,
        colorError: colors.red400,
        colorInfo: colors.blue500,
        colorSuccess: colors.teal500,
        colorWarning: colors.yellow500,
        lime: colors.lime500,
        purple: colors.purple500,
        cyan: colors.cyan500,
        colorLink: colors.blue500,
      }
    }}
  >
```

Seems that with the ConfigProvider it is not working.

The icon color should match the successColor, configured via the ConfigProvider's theme parameter.
I also want to change the message.error, message.warning and message.info color later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Antd documentation you should use the message.useMessage hook as of version 5.

> Why can't ConfigProvider props (like prefixCls and theme) affect
> ReactNode inside message.info, notification.open, Modal.confirm? antd
> will dynamic create React instance by ReactDOM.render when call
> message methods. Whose context is different with origin code located
> context. We recommend useMessage, useNotification and useModal which ,
> the methods came from message/notification/Modal has been deprecated
> in 5.x.

https://ant.design/components/config-provider#locale-is-not-working-with-vite-in-production-mode

Answer (score 0):

### For those who wishes to see a clearer answer

##### An example to change the icon color in `message` of Antd v5

```js
import { Button, ConfigProvider, message } from "antd"; // 1. Import `message` from antd

const TestMessage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [messageApi, contextHolder] = message.useMessage(); // 2. use Hooks to extract the api and the contextHolder

  const btnClickHdlr = (): void => {
    messageApi.success("Test success message!");
    messageApi.error("Test error message!");
    messageApi.info("Test info message!");
    messageApi.warning("Test warning message!");
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* 3. Put the ConfigProvider inside the component you want to modify styling */}
      {/* FYI, this is also one of many weird way to style in Antd. */}
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          token: {
            colorSuccess: "green",
            colorError: "red",
            colorInfo: "blue",
            colorWarning: "yellow",
          },
        }}
      >
        {contextHolder}
        <Button type="primary" onClick={btnClickHdlr}>
          Display normal message
        </Button>
      </ConfigProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestMessage;
```

##### Wrong examples that won't work

Add `style` directly won't work.

```js
import { Button, ConfigProvider, message } from "antd";

const TestMessage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const btnClickHdlr = (): void => {
    message.open({
      type: "info",
      content: "Test info message!",
      style: {
        color: "black", // will not work
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={btnClickHdlr}>
        Display normal message
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestMessage;
```

Style the icon won't work either.

```js
import { Button, message } from "antd";
import { InfoCircleFilled } from "@ant-design/icons";

const TestMessage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const btnClickHdlr = (): void => {
    message.open({
      type: "info",
      content: "Test info message!",
      icon: <InfoCircleFilled color="black" />, // this will also not works
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={btnClickHdlr}>
        Display normal message
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestMessage;
```

Reference:

- https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme
- https://ant.design/components/message#why-i-can-not-access-context-redux-configprovider-localeprefixclstheme-in-message